# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings on hdfs dfs -ls for fresh aws emr 6.5

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hdfs, amazon-emr

i just spun up an aws emr 6.5 cluster, logged on as the hadoop user to the master node, and expected this command to work and show me what is in hdfs.  instead i get:

```
[hadoop@ip-172-31-2-2 ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

what am i doing wrong?  how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a warning. There is nothing that really needs fixed.

There would be no output if your default filesystem is empty at `/home/hadoop` (the directory for the current user)

Try instead `hdfs dfs -ls /home`, for example, or `-put` some file, then `-ls`